# Saving Celery tasks to a Django backend - clearing some confusions

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I started working with `Celery` and integrated it with `Django`, where I have the latest versions of both.

`Celery` is configured in `settings.py` like so:

```
# Celery settings

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

#: Only add pickle to this list if your broker is secured
#: from unwanted access (see userguide/security.html)
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

`djcelary` is installed.

Now I want to do the following: **Store all tasks that have gone through celary in Django's database and have them inspected via django admin**

I have done the following in order to achieve that:

- Run Celary with `-E` in order to capture events
- Run `python manage.py celarycam`

And after this, when I execute tasks, they are added to the database admin.

But here comes my confusion:

- If I don't run the `celarycam` from `manage.py`, nothing is stored (I am looking in the `Tasks` table in `djcelary` part of admin) in the admin
- But If I kill `Celary` and start it again, and ask for the result with a previous `task_id`, I get it.

So Celary Django's backend is storing tasks somewhere but unless i turn the `celarycam` on, I cannot see the tasks in the admin.

**What is the right thing to do in order to see all tasks in my Django admin?**

Also, can I see tasks that are stored somewhere but weren't captured by `celarycam`?

Any comments that can clear my confusion are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In Celery, [Django backend](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/django.html) is **not** supported remote control.

> The Django database transport does not currently support:
>
> - Remote control commands (celery events command, broadcast)
> - Events, including the **Django Admin monitor.**
> - Using more than a few workers (can lead to messages being executed multiple times).

Django backend is [experimental broker](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html).
It may be functional but they do not have dedicated maintainers.